# Date on mysql always 1970

Tags: php, mysql

I want the update my table with the current time when a user does something, I'm using this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) );
$data_insert = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE account.account SET last_vote = '$date' WHERE login = '$account'") or die(mysql_error());
```

The problem is that everything returns '1970-01-01'...

Comment: What is the value of: `$date` ?

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the output

Comment: Before you use it in `strtotime()`..

Comment: what is your $date format? d/m/Y?

Comment: @Rizier123 5248-05-23, using strtotime("now");

Comment: DO u want the current time when inserting the row in the table? date("d-m-Y") would be enough if u want Day-Month-Year.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo If you get this with `strtotime("now");`, then your server time is really messed up! Or you are [`back from the future`](http://goo.gl/9KcDJJ)

Comment: @Falt4rm - d-m-Y might be good if the database recognises it as d-m-Y and doesn't confuse it with the American m-d-Y.... can you tell me whether 02-05-2015 is the 5th or February or the 2nd May?

Comment: Yeah that's why i said "if u want Day-Month-Year". Was betting on a d-m-y based on question formulation. I won xD. English isn't my native language aswell, easier to feel it.

Comment: The `-` seperator does only make sense with ISO yy-mm-dd, US date would use / (or .).

Answer (score 1):

**PHP strtotime() Function**.

> The strtotime() function parses an English textual datetime into a
>   Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00
>   GMT).

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Answer (score 1):

What's the value of `$date`?

If you want it to update with the current time, then use

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", time());
```